# Original CSS not loading after adding custom CSS

Tags: magento-1.9, css, merge-css

My website is not loading CSS of colors and fonts. I'm using a customizable theme but after the day I've added custom CSS like **".brand{ overflow: hidden;} etc"**.

Does doing this disconnected any original CSS file?

Comment: are you using magento 2 ?

Comment: no, i am using magento 1.9

Comment: you did'nt replied aasim